# Create <p> element inside existing div in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a `<div>` element that already exists in my HTML document.
I would like to dynamically add `<p>` elements to it using Dojo.

I am confused about domConstruct create vs. place vs toDom methods. I don't want to create more divs, I just want to place a paragraph element inside the existing div.

How would I go about doing this?

Currently I have this but it doesn't seem to be working I'm assuming because the create method is used to create divs rather than other types of elements :

```
var errorPopup = dom.byId('error-dialog');
for (var i = 0; i < errorMessages.length; i++) {
                      var eMessage = domConstruct.create("<p>'"+errorMessages[i]+"'</p>");
                      errorPopup.appendChild(eMessage);
                  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure why the create method doesn't work (unless my original hunch is correct) but I got it to work with the place method.

```
for (var i = 0; i < errorMessages.length; i++) {
                      var eMessage = domConstruct.place("<p>'"+errorMessages[i]+"'</p>", "error-dialog");
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly `dojo/domConstruct` ,

it has three params `domConstruct.create(arg1,arg2,arg3)`

1. **arg1 :** Dom element to create
2. **arg2 :** json object of argument (attrib of the created elemnt , also it's innerHTML, id , class ...)
3. **arg3 :** the domNode or id of the your created element should be placed

```js
require([ "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/dom", "dojo/ready"], function(domConstruct, dom, ready) {
  ready(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var elment = domConstruct.create('p', {
                       'id': 'tooltipExample' + i,
                         'innerHTML': "Error number " + i
                        }, 
                   "error-dialog");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojoConfig = {
    isDebug: true,
    async: true,
    parseOnLoad: true
  }
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="error-dialog"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although question is answered, just to promote solution without for loop, I'll post it here:

```js
const errors = [
  'Error 1',
  'Error 2',
  'Error 3'
]


require(['dojo/dom-construct'], function(dc) {
  function wrap(error) {
    return '<p>' + error + '</p>'
    //return `<p>${error}</p> also can be used
  }
  
  function place (el) {
    dc.place(el, 'errors')
  }
  
  errors
    .map(wrap)
    .forEach(place)
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<div id='errors'></div>
```